# What is the default value of char in c

Tags: c, local

When I declare an *int* variable, and do not not assign a value to it, and then when I print it, a random number gets printed.

but when I allocate a *char* variable, and print it with `%c` format specifier, nothing is printed. So does a *char* variable in C have a default value like null? Do local variables in C start with a random value? Then why doesn't a *char* behave in this way?

Comment: no variable in C is automatically initialized. You didn't see it just because the value in it isn't in the printable ASCII range

Comment: Many characters aren't printable. The random value (and yes, that's what it will be) may be one of them.

Comment: when I print it with a %d format specifier , 0 is printed. doesn't that mean its default value is set to null

Comment: p.s. if you were to `printf("%i", (int)mychar);` you'd see the random value.

Comment: static and global variables are initialized to the logical equivalent to 0 (NULL for pointers, '\0' for characters, 0 for integers or floating point numbers...).

Comment: And `0` is a perfectly valid "accidental" value for an uninitialized character; just don't count on it.

Comment: @PaulRoub: The value is not random (that term has strict statistical implications), it's merely arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default value which is assigned to it. Some values are not printable and you can assume that random value is one of them, so that is the reason why you are not able to see the result.

The C99 standard says that:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is **indeterminate**.

**On a side note:**

As per C99

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or    unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)    according to these rules;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively)    according to these rules.

Comment: you said there is no default value, but the specification says it is initialized to default values

Comment: @DesirePRG:- Check this:- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf Page 126

Comment: @DesirePRG: Local variables (that is, variables defined within a function or block without the `static` keyword) are not initialized and contain an indeterminate value.  Global and static variables (declared outside of a function or with the `static` keyword) are initialized as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic variables that are not initialized have indeterminate value, we can see this by going to the draft C99 standard section `6.7.8` *Initialization*:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

using an indeterminate value is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The definition for indeterminate values is as follows:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

It just may be the case that the values you are ending up with for char are not printable.

Answer (score 0):

There is not default value assigned. Never trust in a default value you didn't assign.